# ¿Hay algún término para referirse exclusivamente a un hombre homosexual?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, sexualidad

En el DRAE la definición de [homosexual](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KbvDDyj) incluye a personas (ambos sexos) y sus relaciones.

> **homosexual**
>
> Inclinada sexualmente hacia individuos de su mismo sexo.

La entrada de [gay](http://dle.rae.es/?id=J1HLflc) sugiere que es un término que se suele usar más con hombres, pero de nuevo se puede aplicar a cualquier persona indistintamente de su sexo (hombres y mujeres).

> **gay**
>
> Dicho de una persona, especialmente de un hombre: homosexual.

Por el contrario, la entrada de [lesbiana](http://dle.rae.es/?id=N9yxt4g) no deja dudas de que se trata de un término usado solo para mujeres homosexuales.

> **lesbiano, na**
>
> Dicho de una mujer: homosexual.

"Lesbiano" es simplemente "relativo al lesbianismo" o "natural de Lesbos" o "perteneciente a Lesbos".

¿Existe algún término no peyorativo en español que haga la misma distinción respecto a hombres? Es decir que signifique "hombre homosexual" y no "mujer homosexual" ni sea tan genérico o ambiguo como "persona homosexual".

Es decir, si yo digo "esa persona es gay" o "esa persona es homosexual", no necesariamente se sabe su sexo, simplemente que sus preferencia son hacia individuos de su mismo sexo (sea el que sea). Si por el contrario digo "Esa persona es *lesbiana*" se deja patente que esa persona es mujer.

El término por el que pregunto sería tal que podríamos decir "Esa persona es -" y quedaría patente que es un hombre (homosexual), no una mujer, y sería un término que podríamos usar en cualquier contexto (es decir, no es malsonante ni peyorativo).

Comment: ¿Estás buscando un término que no sea despectivo?

Comment: Sí, gracias por la puntualización. Mi idea era poder decir algo como "A pesar de ser ambos miembros del colectivo LGTB, las lesbianas y los _gais_ [hombres homosexuales] a veces no se llevan bien". Usando _gay_, alguien me podría matizar que, _técnicamente_, las lesbianas también son gais. No hay ningún problema en usar "hombres homosexuales" en esa frase (y desde luego es preferible a cualquier opción peyorativa), pero mi idea al lanzar la pregunta era ver si podíamos aprender algún término nuevo.

Comment: gracias por explicar la motivación.  Sí, *gay* tiene dos acepciones.  Creo que "gay" es suficiente para dar a entender *hombre homosexual* en la mayoría de los contextos, incluyendo el ejemplo que diste; y cuando podría haber duda, se podría dejar más claro usando "hombres gay".  Y fíjate que creo que esto es también lo que se hace en inglés. // Gracias por aclara lo que buscas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

¿Y qué tal [**uranista**](https://dle.rae.es/uranista?)?:

> 1. adj. cult. Dicho de un hombre: homosexual. U. t. c. s. m.

La definición lo restringe a los hombres, y no es malsonante ni peyorativo.

Comment: Gran descubrimiento. Acepto encantado que Diego me haya quitado la marca de respuesta aceptada y te la haya dado a ti. Te damos la bienvenida al sitio, y esperamos más colaboraciones tuyas igual o más interesantes. :-)

Answer (score 6):

Imagino que no seré el primero al que se haya ocurrido, pero buscando en el DIRAE vaya si hay palabras registradas con el significado de *[hombre homosexual](https://dirae.es/palabras/?q=hombre%20homosexual)*, desde las más coloridas y ocurrentes hasta las más bastas y explícitas. Y, por supuesto, cada una aplica en un país diferente.

Sin embargo, yo entiendo que *gay* se refiere principalmente a los hombres. Yo, al menos, lo he entendido siempre así, aunque imagino que el término se puede usar indistintamente. La verdad es que mirando el diccionario veo que *gay* siempre ha sido sinónima de *homosexual*, y este término se aplica a ambos sexos por igual.

Si nos salimos de la RAE, lo que se me ocurre es comprobar cómo se llama al colectivo que representa a las diferentes personas homosexuales, bisexuales, transexuales y demás: [LGTB](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGBT). En esta sigla la *L* y la *G* corresponden, respectivamente, a las [lesbianas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lesbianidad) y los [gais](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gay). Y se denominan así, por separado, y no agrupando a hombres y mujeres bajo una única inicial. Y si nos vamos a las dos definiciones en la Wikipedia que acabo de enlazar, vemos:

- Lesbianismo es el término empleado en español para hacer referencia a la homosexualidad femenina, es decir, las mujeres que experimentan amor romántico o atracción sexual por otras mujeres.
- La palabra gay​ es una manera de designar a las personas homosexuales masculinas, es decir, a los hombres que les atraen sexual y emocionalmente otros hombres.

Y este último artículo aclara:

> En países hispanohablantes, *gay* se refiere casi exclusivamente al género masculino (por lo tanto, no se aplica a las mujeres lesbianas o transexuales).

En mi opinión, la palabra *gay* se usa para ambos sexos por comodidad y ahorro en términos como el *matrimonio gay*, o la *comunidad gay* (aunque este se está perdiendo en favor de la *comunidad LGTB*), o incluso las *personas gais* en general. Pero si te fijas, normalmente se dice *un gay* y no *una gay*, sino *una lesbiana*. De ahí que referido a personas, *gay* implique un hombre (salvo, claro está, que quieras ocultar intencionadamente el sexo de la persona de la que hablas, pero esa es otra cuestión).

Por último, hacer notar que el término *gay* fue el adoptado por la propia comunidad gay. Por tanto, cualquier otro término que encuentres (véase la lista enlazada al principio) podría tener connotaciones negativas o despectivas.

Comment: +1, Sí, cierto. Esa era más o menos mi idea al lanzar la pregunta, pero quería ver si alguien salía con algún término poco conocido. Supongo que con el tiempo la definición de _gay_ (del DRAE) se actualizará para recoger que el uso que le estamos dando es más de "hombre homosexual" que el más general "persona homosexual".